# How to change Table row colour based on content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wanna fill a table with content coming from a php request. According to the content i have 4 status i want to use to define the bootstrap TR class.

Below is my snippet. I assigned the class to the TR already, but this might have to be changed.

The rule should is already shown in the TR class in the snippet below.

The condition is as below:

**Expected = bg-success**

**Cancelled = bg-danger**

**Inhouse = bg-info**

**Partial = bg-warning**

**Finished = bg-active**

Sine i wanna use php foreach or while to fill the table, how can i make the table change colour of the row dynamic using javascript or jquery?

```js
function reservationListFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("reservationListInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("reservationTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#reservationTable tr').each(function () {
       var td_value = $('td',this).eq(3).text();
       switch (td_value) {
           case 'Partial':
                $(this).addClass('bg-warning');
               break;
               ....
               And So On
               ....
           default:
               // statements_def
               break;
       }
    });
});
```

```css
#reservationListInput {
  background-image: url('./assets/fonts/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#reservationTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}

#reservationTable th,
#reservationTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add padding */
}

#reservationTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#reservationTable tr.header,
#reservationTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

<table id="reservationTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Cabin</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Table</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-success">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>49222</td>
    <td>201</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-info">
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>12846</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-danger">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>11847</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Does your PHP serve a HTML snippet? What is the condition for the row color?

Comment: use css selectors to give dynamic colours

Comment: Based on the `class` the `tr` already has?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the condition. It is the last <td> as example: <td>Expected</td> if it is equal to Expected than use class="bg-success" and so on. Maybe I can give this TD a class and check the content is equal to a predefined list?

Comment: Does your PHP serve an HTML snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working example of my answer...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#reservationTable tr').each(function () {
       var td_value = $('td',this).eq(3).text();
       console.log(td_value);
       switch (td_value) {
           case 'Expected':
                $(this).addClass('bg-success');
               break;

           default:
               // statements_def
               break;
       }
    });
});
```

```css
#reservationListInput {
  background-image: url('./assets/fonts/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#reservationTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}

#reservationTable th,
#reservationTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add padding */
}

#reservationTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#reservationTable tr.header,
#reservationTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

<table id="reservationTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Cabin</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Table</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>49222</td>
    <td>201</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>12846</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>11847</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you delete one of the answers?

Comment: This may solve your problem and the other answer may solve other buddy's problem. The answers are not solely to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this gives you some insight...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#reservationTable tr').each(function () {
       var td_value = $('td',this).eq(3).text();
       switch (td_value) {
           case 'Partial':
                $(this).addClass('bg-warning');
               break;
               ....
               And So On
               ....
           default:
               // statements_def
               break;
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: My row piece would look like this:

<tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>

And i would add the class dynamically based on yourJS, correct?

Comment: Yeah. don't add any classes before the output of HTML or from PHP.

Comment: I added this JS to the Code snippet, and changed the TD to its initial. But the code you have posted doesn't change the colour.

Comment: Could you delete one of the answers?

Comment: Why? Actually both answers are different in their aspect. The answers may help someone else...

Comment: They are basically the same with one being more elaborate than the other.

Comment: This is just an hint and the other is working example. Was this answer able to help you? If you any problem please flag the answer.

Comment: This did the trick. But i had to use table-active for bootstrap 4 use. Thanks so much.

Comment: bs3 and bs4 are very different things... :) :D

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that bootstrap classes aren't working ... only then my answer is solution to your question.

You haven't included the bootstrap CSS file in your html page or made some mistake while doing so.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

This is the line you should include in `<head></head>` tags.

Here is the demo : [DEMO for you code](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish1269/979bumkg/)

See closely, I didn't change anything in your code.

P.S. If this isn't the solution then I am not able to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to iterate over the `status` column and set the `background-color` based on the text:

```js
var colors = {
  Expected: '#90EE90',
  Inhouse: '#ADD8E6',
  Cancelled: '#FF0000',
  Partial: '#FFA500'
};

$('tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);  
  $this.parent().css('background-color', colors[$this.text()]);
});
```

```css
#reservationListInput {
  background-image: url('./assets/fonts/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#reservationTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}

#reservationTable th,
#reservationTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add padding */
}

#reservationTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#reservationTable tr.header,
#reservationTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

<table id="reservationTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Cabin</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Table</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-success">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>49222</td>
    <td>201</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-info">
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>12846</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-danger">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>11847</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-warning">
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should take the Bootstrap class. And adding a class to the <tr> seems to be the better way.

Comment: Understood, My answer was if you have to do it in the frontend with JavaScript based on the text of the column status.. But yes, if you render with the class name from the server it will be much better!